# Scala Play 2.8 FieldConstructor type and IntelliJ: Cannot resolve symbol f

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, playframework, sbt

I'm trying to write my own custom field constructor using the [documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.8.x/ScalaCustomFieldConstructors) for Play 2.8.

Following the docs, I created this identical sample constructor:

```
@(elements: helper.FieldElements)

<div class="@if(elements.hasErrors) {error}">
    <label for="@elements.id">@elements.label</label>
    <div class="input">
        @elements.input
        <span class="errors">@elements.errors.mkString(", ")</span>
        <span class="help">@elements.infos.mkString(", ")</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I named it `app/views/myFieldConstructor.scala.html`. (I had earlier tried to name it `myFieldConstructor.f`; play's documentation isn't great here.)

Then elsewhere, I created a scala Object named `app/forms/auth/AuthFieldConstructor`:

```
package forms.auth

import views.html

object AuthFieldConstructor {
  import views.html.helper.FieldConstructor
  implicit val myFields: FieldConstructor = FieldConstructor(html.myFieldConstructor.f)
}
```

My IDE is complaining that `f` cannot be found, and it also infers the type
of `html.myFieldConstructor` as `myFieldConstructor.type`.

I *am* able to `@import forms.auth.AuthFieldConstructor._` in my other templates, and the code compiles and the form renders, but I'm bugged that my IDE isn't inferring this correctly.

Exploring it a little more, this code still compiles but the `f` is still unrecognized:

```
object AuthFieldConstructor {
  import views.html.helper.FieldConstructor
  val fieldConstructor: myFieldConstructor.type = html.myFieldConstructor
  implicit val myFields: FieldConstructor = FieldConstructor(fieldConstructor.f)
}
```

I've come across `.type` before, when forgetting to apply an object, but adding `apply` or `()` here doesn't help. Any ideas how to make my IDE recognize what is happening here?

I have Scala compile server turned off. I am using sbt shell for both project reload and builds. I have "Use Play 2 compiler for this project" checked. Scala 2.13.3, sbt 1.3.13, Play 2.8.2 .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not really sure of the answer to the type inference oddness, but I was able to get the IDE to stop complaining, first by grabbing a clue from this [old PR](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/pull/111/files) to change the scala object's code for the field constructor helper:

```
  implicit val authFieldConstructor = new FieldConstructor {
    override def apply(elements: FieldElements): Html = myFieldConstructor(elements)
  }
```

A couple of IDE transformations later and I ended up with the cleaner:

```
  implicit val authFieldConstructor: FieldConstructor = (elements: FieldElements) => myFieldConstructor(elements)
```